# ICEFaces 3.1: NullPointerException raised while re-rendering a view

Tags: java, xml, icefaces, spring-webflow, icefaces-3

I'm facing a problem with ICEFaces. It seems like it's unable to properly refresh a view.
I'll provide you with the view, the flow, the bean and the details of the strange behaviour  I found thanks to some debugging sessions.

Basically, I'm dealing with a lazy loaded ace:DataTable.

```
<ace:dataTable id="blocchiTable" [..] />
```

I select some rows and click on a button labeled with "Modifica" (the Italian for "Edit"):

```
<ace:menuItem id="modificaBloccoButton" value="Modifica" action="modificaBlocco" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" />`
```

As you will see in the flow, the related click event leads the flow to a decision-state:

```
<view-state id="creablocco" view="creablocco.xhtml">
    [.. other stuff ..]
    <transition on="modificaBlocco" to="decidiModifica">
        <evaluate expression="flowScope.blocchiBean.getRigheSelezionate()" result="flowScope.righeSelezionate"/>
    </transition>
</view-state>
<decision-state id="decidiModifica">
    <if test="!(flowScope.righeSelezionate).isEmpty()" then="modificaBlocco" else="fine" />
</decision-state>
```

and, afterwards, another view-state, associated to the same view of the initial state. While entering the new view-state, the flow asks the bean to enable the cellEditor for the proper rows, so that, when the view is re-rendered, the selected rows will be editable.

```
<view-state id="modificaBlocco" view="creablocco.xhtml">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="flowScope.blocchiBean.abilitaModifica()"/>
    </on-entry>    
    <transition on="salvaModificheBlocco" to="fine">
        <evaluate expression="flowScope.blocchiBean.salvaBlocchi()"/>
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

Unfortunaly, while re-rendering the view (I already checked that the method specified in the `<on-entry>` section is actually invoked), the following **exception** is raised:

```
AVVERTENZA: queued exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.isWhitespaceText(DOMUtils.java:394)
    at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.printNode(DOMUtils.java:351)
    at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.printNode(DOMUtils.java:355)
    at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.printNode(DOMUtils.java:355)
    at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.printNode(DOMUtils.java:355)
    at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.printNode(DOMUtils.java:306)
    at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.printNode(DOMUtils.java:290)
    at org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.endDocument(DOMResponseWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:410)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.render(FlowLifecycle.java:80)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.render(JsfView.java:89)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:243)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:221)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.traceNextValve(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:112)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

This is the **complete view**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components" 
                xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                template="/resources/includes/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="pageTitle" value="Crea blocco" />
    <ui:define name="page-content">
        <ace:panel id="personalInfoInputPanel" header="Crea blocco">
            <div class="div_creablocco">
                <h:form id="creabloccoform">
                    <h:panelGrid id="creabloccoInputGrid" columns="1" styleClass="table_creablocco">
                        <ace:textEntry id="numeroFile" value="#{creaBloccoBean.numeroFile}" label="Numero file:" labelPosition="left" required="true" requiredIndicator="(*)" indicatorPosition="right">
                        </ace:textEntry>
                        <ace:textEntry id="numeroColonne" value="#{creaBloccoBean.numeroColonne}" label="Numero colonne:" labelPosition="left" required="true" requiredIndicator="(*)" indicatorPosition="right">
                        </ace:textEntry>
                        <ace:textEntry id="posizioneX" value="#{creaBloccoBean.posizioneX}" label="Coordinata X:" labelPosition="left" required="true" requiredIndicator="(*)" indicatorPosition="right">
                        </ace:textEntry>
                        <ace:textEntry id="posizioneY" value="#{creaBloccoBean.posizioneY}" label="Coordinata Y:" labelPosition="left" required="true" requiredIndicator="(*)" indicatorPosition="right">
                        </ace:textEntry>
                        <ace:pushButton id="pushBttnCreaBlocco"  value="Crea blocco" action="creaBlocco"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </ace:panel>

        <ace:panel id="blocchiPanel" header="Blocchi">
            <h:form id="blocchiTableForm">
                <ace:menuBar id="iconeBloccoMenu" rendered="#{!blocchiBean.modificaInCorso}">
                    <ace:menuItem id="dettagliBloccoButton" value="Dettagli" action="dettagliBlocco" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search" />
                    <ace:menuItem id="modificaBloccoButton" value="Modifica" action="modificaBlocco" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" />
                    <ace:menuItem id="cancellaBloccoButton" value="Cancella" action="cancellaBlocco" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" />
                </ace:menuBar>
                <ace:menuBar id="iconeModificaBloccoMenu" rendered="#{flowScope.blocchiBean.modificaInCorso}">
                    <ace:menuItem id="annullaModificheButton" value="Annulla" action="annullaModificheBlocco" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-w" />
                    <ace:menuItem id="salvaModifiche" value="Salva" action="salvaModificheBlocco" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-disk" />
                </ace:menuBar>
                <ace:dataTable id="blocchiTable" value="#{blocchi}"
                    binding="#{flowScope.blocchiBean.table}" stateMap="#{flowScope.blocchiBean.stateMap}"
                    selectionMode="multiple" doubleClickSelect="false"
                    rowSelectListener="#{flowScope.blocchiBean.selectListener}"
                    rowUnselectListener="#{flowScope.blocchiBean.deselectListener}" var="blocco"
                    lazy="true" rows="10" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom">
                    <ace:column id="idBloccoColumn" headerText="ID" styleClass="id">
                        <h:outputText id="idBloccoText" value="#{blocco.id}" />
                    </ace:column>
                    <ace:column id="numeroFileBloccoColumn" headerText="Numero file"
                        styleClass="numFile">
                        <ace:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText id="numeroFileBloccoText"
                                    value="#{blocco.numeroFile}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <h:inputText id="numeroFileBloccoInput"
                                    value="#{blocco.numeroFile}" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </ace:cellEditor>

                    </ace:column>
                    <ace:column id="numeroColonneBloccoColumn"
                        headerText="Numero colonne" styleClass="numColonne">
                        <ace:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText id="numeroColonneBloccoText"
                                    value="#{blocco.numeroColonne}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <h:inputText id="numeroColonneBloccoInput"
                                    value="#{blocco.numeroColonne}" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </ace:cellEditor>

                    </ace:column>
                    <ace:column id="posizioneXBloccoColumn" headerText="Posizione X"
                        styleClass="posX">
                        <ace:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText id="posizioneXBloccoText"
                                    value="#{blocco.posizioneX}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <h:inputText id="posizioneXBloccoInput"
                                    value="#{blocco.posizioneX}" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </ace:cellEditor>

                    </ace:column>
                    <ace:column id="posizioneYBloccoColumn" headerText="Posizione Y"
                        styleClass="posY">
                        <ace:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText id="posizioneYBloccoText"
                                    value="#{blocco.posizioneY}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <h:inputText id="posizioneYBloccoInput"
                                    value="#{blocco.posizioneY}" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </ace:cellEditor>

                    </ace:column>
                </ace:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </ace:panel>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

This is the **complete flow**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <var name="creaBloccoBean" class="com.infoone.siglo.viewbeans.CreaBloccoBean" />
    <var name="blocchiBean" class="com.infoone.siglo.viewbeans.BlocchiBean" />

    <view-state id="creablocco" view="creablocco.xhtml">
        <on-entry>
            <evaluate expression="flowScope.blocchiBean.getBlocchi()" result="flowScope.blocchi" />
        </on-entry>
        <transition on="creaBlocco" to="fine">
            <evaluate expression="gestoreBlocchiCtr.creaBlocco(creaBloccoBean)" />
        </transition>
        <transition on="cancellaBlocco" to="decidiCancellazione">
            <evaluate expression="flowScope.blocchiBean.getRigheSelezionate()" result="flowScope.righeSelezionate"/>
        </transition>
        <transition on="modificaBlocco" to="decidiModifica">
            <evaluate expression="flowScope.blocchiBean.getRigheSelezionate()" result="flowScope.righeSelezionate"/>
        </transition>
    </view-state>

    <decision-state id="decidiCancellazione">
        <if test="!(flowScope.righeSelezionate).isEmpty()" then="cancellaBlocco" else="fine" />
    </decision-state>
    <decision-state id="decidiModifica">
        <if test="!(flowScope.righeSelezionate).isEmpty()" then="modificaBlocco" else="fine" />
    </decision-state>

    <action-state id="cancellaBlocco">
        <evaluate expression="gestoreBlocchiCtr.rimuoviBlocchi(flowScope.righeSelezionate)" />
        <transition to="fine"/>
    </action-state>
    <view-state id="modificaBlocco" view="creablocco.xhtml">
        <on-entry>
            <evaluate expression="flowScope.blocchiBean.abilitaModifica()"/>
        </on-entry>    
        <transition on="salvaModificheBlocco" to="fine">
            <evaluate expression="flowScope.blocchiBean.salvaBlocchi()"/>
        </transition>
    </view-state>

    <end-state id="fine" />

</flow>
```

I tried to understand which UI component was causing such an exception and, luckily, I was able to isolate it by launching the webapp on a debugging-mode server.
Basically, it is a `<script>` node with 22 textElement children. The third child is causing the exception:

```
<script>
    |------ null_icefaces_config
    |------ ', '
    |------ null <<===== (This is the node which causes the exception. I mean exactly the null value associated to the "NULL type", here)
    |------ ', '
    |------ unknownWindow
    |------ [.. other children ..]
```

I also inspected the content of the *writer* object, which is the object containing the output stream that is gradually filled with the content of the response. The portion generated by rendering this element is:

```
<script>ice.setupBridge('null_icefaces_config
```

Have you ever faced a similar problem? Do you think I should report this case to the ICEFaces staff, so that they can check whether it's a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an issue with the way the Webflow navigation model integrates with JSF. The ICEFaces code uses a phase listener to extract bits of information from the request and this phase listener isn't executed in the GET portion of the POST-Redirect-GET Spring navigation model. There is a workaround, which is to implement a FlowExecutionListener which takes the place of the PhaseListener in those circumstances. See the tutorial and example implementation of the Listener here:

http://wiki.icesoft.org/display/ICE/Spring+Web+Flow+2.3.1

Comment: Thanks. Thanks!
It was only my fault. I actually followed that sample but, due to a lapse of concentration, I deleted EXACTLY THAT LISTENER from the list of webflow:listeners and substituted it with another one, instead of simply adding the latter one. Such an act of carelessness led me to two days of useless debugging. :-S